# If you perturb a polynomial by a smooth function, then is the signed number of small zeros of the perturbed equation the same as the lowest non zero derivative?

Tags: differential-topology, real-analysis, complex-geometry, ag.algebraic-geometry

Let $f: \mathbb{C} \rightarrow \mathbb{C} $ be a function of the form

$$ f(z) = z^n + z^{n+ 1} g(z) $$
where $g$ is a $\textbf{smooth}$ function (not necessarily holomorphic).

Is it true that the number of solutions counted with a sign ``near'' the origin
for the equation 
$$ f(z)-\nu =0 $$ 
is $n$, where $\nu$ is a small perturbation? More precisely, this is 
what I mean:

Let $\nu : \mathbb{C} \rightarrow \mathbb{C}$ be a smooth function that 
is zero outside a compact set.  Let the supremum norm (which makes sense) be less than $\epsilon$. 
Consider the equation 
$$f(z) -\nu =0 $$
restricted to an open ball of radius $R$. Also assume that restricted 
to this open ball zero is a regular value of the function 
$f(z) - \nu(z)$. (I think one can show such a $\nu$ exists, 
in fact any generic $\nu$ will satisfy that).  Hence now we can ask 
how many solutions does the equation 
$$ f(z) - \nu(z) =0$$ 
have inside a ball of radius $R$. My question is that if 
$\epsilon$ and $R$ are sufficiently small then is it going to be $n$? Its certainly true if $g$ was holomorphic.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The answer is yes. Actualy Rouche's theorem is valid for smooth functions if instead of
the number of zeros you count the signed number. (I suppose that this is what you want to count).
That is the zero with positive Jacobian is counted
with + and zero with negative Jacobian is counted with -. This is called the topological degree.

Comment: Thank you, that is exactly what I want to count. Is there a reference for this fact (that Rouche's theorem 
is valid for smooth functions)? 

Comment: In general, topological degree is explained in Milnor's book Topology
from differentiable viewpoint, but perhaps there is no exact statement
of Rouche's thm there. When I used a similar fact in my own paper,
I refered to MR1789408 
M. Cristea,
A generalization of the argument principle,
Complex Variables Theory Appl. 42 (2000), no. 4, 333–345. 